# how to read Excel file ifyou have some multivalue in nodejs

Tags: node.js

[excel Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBUU0.png)
I have an Excel file like this and I want to convert in an array of JSON object. I know how to do if I have a single value but how to for multivalue?